# 1991 F150 Power steering failed

Tags: ford, power-steering, f-150

i have a 91 f150 xlt lariat, 5.8l. I had to make a hard turn in reverse over a curb. The steering wheel was pulled as far as I could to the right. I got over the curb, but when I did the steering felt off, like it was stiff while turning right. I went straight home and just as I pulled in I completely lost power steering. I just got the truck a month a go, don't see anything visibly wrong, but I'm new with these things. The person I bought it off said there was a very minor power steering leak but there's still plenty of fluid. I should note the steering was pretty loose before this happened and owners previous mechanic recommended to replace the steering gear box, if that makes a difference.Any ideas? Thanks!

Update: I did let the car sit for an hour and the power steering worked again for about 5 minutes before failing again. Just FYI in case that helps.

Comment: While I get you're having a problem with your steering, I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to solve.  Could you please edit your question and specify your question better?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I guess I'm just looking for some potential causes of the problem. Why my power steering would fail after reversing over a curb, with the steering wheel turned hard right.

Answer (score 2):

It has been diagnosed once with a bad steering gear. But to be sure you can isolate the leak. If the leak is not in the gear, then repair the leak. Then have the pump pressure checked. If pump pressure is in spec you probably have a bad steering gear. I don't think this truck has rack and pinion steering.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll look into this. I let the car cool a bit and strangely the power steering worked for about 5 minutes before failing again. Does that help narrow anything down?